# How to get index of the selected item in JFace TableViewer?

Tags: swt, jface

I am using a `ISelectionChangedListener` to listen to a selection event on JFace TableViewer. Is there a way to get the index of the selected row?

```all
tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
 {
     @Override
     public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent selectionEvent)
     {             
         final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) historyTableViewer.getSelection();
         if (selection != null)
         {
            selectedEvent = (castToObject) selection.getFirstElement();

         }
     }
 });
```

So, say I selected the 4th row out of the 8 rows in the TableViewer. How do I know the selection corresponds to 4th row?

Answer (score 4):

You can ask the underlying `Table` control for the selection index:

```all
int index = tableViewer.getTable().getSelectionIndex();
```

or for multiple selection:

```all
int [] indices = tableViewer.getTable().getSelectionIndices();
```

But when you are using `TableViewer` you generally don't use row indices.

Answer (score -1):

```
int index=tableViewer.getTable().getSelectionIndex();

return tableViewer.getElementAt(index)
```

****for return object selected to tableviewer ****